# How to calculate tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, string

below is an experiment set up to test the effect tension has on the frequency of various guitar strings. It's hard to see the string in the picture, but it's attached to a weight and I was wondering how you could calculate the tension on the string? What equation/formula would you use? We know the length, mass of the string.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image].        Here i have depicted it pictorially .you can see the image.

Answer (score 1):

The tension on the string is equal to the weight of the hanging object, plus the weight of the string that is hanging from the pulley. To calculate this, measure the hanging length, $l$. Then, for a string of mass $M$ and length $L$, the mass of the hanging portion is $m=M\frac{l}{L}$.

Comment: This is assuming a string of negligible mass, so it is actually that weight, plus the weight of the string hanging from the pully

Comment: @Natecat Ah, yeah, sorry for forgetting that. My implicit point, though, is that currently, you won't get more than one data point with this setup.

Comment: Well, obviously you would have to vary an aspect of the experiment in order to get multiple data points, and it's implicit in the question they have already handled that (Varying the amount of weight hanging from the string). His question was specifically, how can they calculate the tension during one trial.

Comment: yes @Natecat is correct, I am just looking to calculate the tension for one of the data points/trials.